# Injury to hotel guest due to negligence on hotel's part

Tags: safety, spain

We are residents in Germany and are holidaying in Mallorca, Spain.

Last night my wife suffered a deep cut to her toe because the bottom edge of a glass door in our room does not have adequate protection.

Does the hotel have liability for my wife’s injury? Are we entitled to a compensation for the personal injury caused?

See attached photo for additional detail.
[image]

Comment: Did you book the room with the hotel directly or did you book a complete package (flight+accommodation+transfer+...) with a German travel agency? This does make a difference regarding who is your point of contact.

Comment: http://www.holidaycare.org.uk/holiday-accident-claims/spain-holiday-accident-claims makes me think that you might be able to claim it as a "Minor injuries – 7-day recovery"

Comment: @DCTLib We booked the room directly with the hotel.

Comment: @neubert thanks for the pointer. Meanwhile, the hotel claims that the door installation is technically appropriate as it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injury to hotel guest due to negligence on hotel's part](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44262/injury-to-hotel-guest-due-to-negligence-on-hotels-part)

Answer (score 3):

I would let the hotel know about it.

If the injury requires a hospital visit that resulted in costs then, I would contact your travel (and/or personal) insurances and ask them how to deal with it.

The main question you have to ask yourself, is it worth it to spend the time and effort (which equals money in the end) to try to "gain" something from the hotel ?

Comment: The hotel responded that it’s technically OK to leave the edge of the glass door unprotected. But I don’t agree with that suggestion and, I would not be satisfied with that response being a resolution for the issue.

Comment: The issue goes back to the same thing: how much time and effort and money are you willing to spend to prove one way or the other that the hotel was negligent.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don’t agree with that suggestion and, I would not be satisfied
> with that response being a resolution for the issue

I am afraid that I have seen such glass doors in bathrooms even in
Germany. May be the building rules of Spain allow that type of
construction.

> Does the hotel have liability for my wife’s injury? Are we entitled to
> a compensation for the personal injury caused?
>
> We are residents in Germany and are holidaying in Mallorca, Spain.

Since you are a resident of Germany - you should be have been covered by 'German insurance' that is also valid in Spain (valid in all EU). Did you pay for the doctor/medical attendant or hospital?

Whether you just want to stop at medical bills or claim extra compensation for lost time/stress/holiday time. This only a lawyer can say.